# Standardizing company names

Tags: pandas, group-by, fuzzywuzzy

I have a list of company names, but these have misspelling and variations. How best can I fix this so every company has the consistent naming convention (for later `groupby`, `sort_value`, etc.)?

```
pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['Disney','Dinsey', 'Walt Disney','General Motors','General Motor','GM','GE','General Electric','J.P. Morgan','JP Morgan']})
```

Answer (score 0):

One good hint: FuzzyWuzzy library. "Fuzzy string matching like a boss. It uses Levenshtein Distance to calculate the differences between sequences in a simple-to-use package."
Example:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz    

str2Match = "apple inc"
strOptions = ["Apple Inc.","apple park","apple incorporated"]
Ratios = process.extract(str2Match,strOptions)
print(Ratios)
# You can also select the string with the highest matching percentage
highest = process.extractOne(str2Match,strOptions)
print(highest)
```

output:

```
[('Apple Inc.', 100), ('apple incorporated', 90), ('apple park', 67)]
('Apple Inc.', 100)
```

Now you just have to create a list with the "right names" and run all the variations against it so you can pick the best ratio and replace it on your dataset.

Comment: Thanks - I'm thinking the same, but my challenge is that the list of 'good name' keep changing.

Comment: humm.. can't you automate a script to scrap it from a site?